# Notice users at stackoverflow about our community if asking questions about salesforce?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I always notice that many questions *about salesforce* are asked over there. Sometimes I remind the new user that there is also an extra forum for Salesforce under stackexchange so we can get more questions and users here. Do you think it is okay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Defo ok !

Even that our site is still in Beta, I think we have a steady ground of users here. It's something SO might not like, but it's the standard way of things with new sites.

Comment: Any idea when StackExchange | Salesforce goes GA (as opposed to Beta)?

Comment: It was mentioned in the SE podcast that it had graduated... but that was a while back already — not sure how long the process takes!