# What should we be doing about Stack Overflow Salesforce questions?

Tags: discussion

On the one hand, I understand the impulse to ignore Salesforce questions on Stack Overflow.  There's more clueless newbies and more "write my code" type questions.  Those posting the questions are also less likely to respond or accept an answer.

On the other hand, if we just ignore them, they may not find the Salesforce Beta site.  Sure, we wouldn't miss some of them, but it would be a shame to miss out on people who could be (or might develop into) strong contributors.

Should we:

1. Invite absolutely everyone who posts Salesforce questions on Stack Overflow to post here?
2. Invite those whose questions show some effort? (with some allowance for being new)
3. Invite those whose questions don't duplicate what is in Salesforce Beta?

I think the right answer falls somewhere between 1 and 2.  I think we need more participants here.  I don't think we can just stock the pond with large fish, so we're going to have to build our pool of users.  What do you thnk?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you speaking of questions posed on other SE sites about SF or those posed here on SF.SE?

Comment: The ones I think are getting less attention are on: "http://stackoverflow.com/" tagged as Salesforce or with other Salesforce-related tags.  Here on "http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/", I think we do more for newer people.  I'm wondering why there's not a more organized effort to recruit new participants from there to here.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Saariko in [Notice users at stackoverflow about our community if asking questions about salesforce?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/notice-users-at-stackoverflow-about-our-community-if-asking-questions-about-sale?rq=1) most likely provides the essence of the *best answer* to your question when he speaks of "the standard way of things with new sites". It would seem that further comment would best be left to him or one of the other moderators.